# Complicated infinite sum convergence

Tags: calculus

Do the following infinite sums
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+n}{n}b^{n}\text{ and }\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+n}{n}a^{m}
$$
converge? If so how to calculate their limit (the $m+n$ in the binomial coefficient confuses me)?

Comment: Think about [generalized binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on $b$ and $a$, obviously... and they are really the same sum, as:

$$
\binom{m + n}{n} = \binom{m + n}{m}
$$

If you expand by the extended binomial theorem:

$\begin{align*}
   (1 + a)^{-r}
      &= \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-r}{k} a^k \\
      &= \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{r + k - 1}{r - 1} a^k \\
      &= \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{r - 1 + k}{k} a^k
\end{align*}$

Your sum is just:

$\begin{align*}
   (1 - a)^{-(m + 1)}
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n \binom{(m + 1) - 1 + n}{n} (-a)^n \\
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{m + n}{n} a^n
\end{align*}$

As for the binomial coefficient:

$\begin{align*}
   \binom{-r}{k}
     &= \frac{(-r)^{\underline{k}}}{k!} \\
     &= \frac{(-r) (-r - 1) \dotsm (-r - (k + 1))}{k!} \\
     &= (-1)^k \frac{r (r + 1) \dotsm (r + k - 1)}{k!} \\
     &= (-1)^k \frac{(r + k - 1)^{\underline{k}}}{k!} \\
     &= (-1)^k \binom{r + k - 1}{k} \\
     &= (-1)^k \binom{r + k - 1}{r - 1}
\end{align*}$

(This uses Knuth's notation for falling factorial powers).

Rounding up: As the binomial series for powers that aren't positive integers converges only for $\lvert a \rvert < 1$, that is the range of validity for your series.

Comment: Thank you very much, that problem was driving me crazy. I didn't even know there was so much to the binomial coefficient.